# Invalid Code Signing. The executable 'Payload/myapp.app/Frameworks/PKHUD.framework' must e signed with the certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipa, mbprogresshud

Just facing an error in an Objectice-C project where I'm using `MBProgressHUD` framework [link: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD]. When I generate a debug build it works fine but it doesn't work and popout an error when I try to generate a signed iOS build.

Note: I'm using the iXGuard in my project, and it works fine without this library, I tried to *keep* this framework & classes but no resolution. Not sure what am I missing.

[image]

Comment: Could you please copy out the whole error message. The messages in your screenshot is truncated. Also , the error messages are thrown in Xcode's Archive phase, right? What's the PKHUB framwork, is it a embedded framework dependency or swift package dependency?

Comment: Yes it is an embedded framework dependency, the app is written in `Objective-C`.